# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE' in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have downloaded Zend latest version(Zend Framework 1.11), then created the project using command line tool.

Also I've created controller in the created project. In the created controller Just I've added new method,

```
<?php

class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function init()
{
    /* Initialize action controller here */
}

public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
}

public function chatAction()
{

    echo 'Test';

}


}
```

then tried to access in the browser

```
http://localhost/user/chat
```

I got the following error

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE' in F:\xampp\htdocs\z_app\application\controllers\ErrorController.php on line 16
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What class-constants are defined in `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler`?

Comment: @MikeB in F:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin I could find the following code `const EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE = 'EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE';`

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the wrong zend library included.

Check your version via `echo Zend_Version::VERSION;` in index.php and die() before bootstrapping (as your mvc is broken).

You may need to update your include path to the correct location of the 1.11 zend framework library. Probably you have multiple versions (i.e. zend studio comes with its own) installed.

Comment: While echoing it shows as "1.9.0". And also the include path shows to the actual Zend/library directory. In F:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin I could find the following code const EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE = 'EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE';

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friends, Finally I resolved the issue by just copying the Zend directory inside of the library of Zend framework directory to my project directory. Now it is working.

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library
```

To

```
F:\xampp\htdocs\z_app\library
```

Even though I've added the include path in the php.ini to the zend framework library directory like below,

```
include_path = ".;F:\xampp\php\PEAR;F:\xampp\htdocs\zend\library
```

It wasn't working.